# Flipping the live feed using QCamera

Tags: c++, qt

I have the Qlabel widget(object name = label_2) on the mainwindow. I display the live feed from camera on this widget. Everything is working fine. However i am wondering how can i change the orientation of live feed (say i want to flip it by 90°).

```
QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras)
{
    if (cameraInfo.deviceName() == "@device:pnp:\\\\?\\pci#ven_109e&dev_036e&subsys_00000000&rev_11#5&12a6b002&0&000008#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\\global")
    cM2 = new QCamera(cameraInfo, this);
}
cV2 = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
cM2->setViewfinder(cV2);
cBox2 = new QVBoxLayout();
cBox2->addWidget(cV2);
ui->label_2->setLayout(cBox2);
cM2->start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCameraViewfinder does not rotate, so you might be better served using a QGraphicsVideoviewer.

Something like:

```
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>

videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
videoItem->setSize(QSizeF(640, 480));

GraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(scene);

scene->addItem(videoItem);

cM2->setViewfinder(videoItem);
videoItem->setTransform(QTransform().rotate(90));

cBox2->addWidget(graphicsView);
```

Comment: Hi QCamera does not have this function. Where did you saw it? Probably its QImage!!

Comment: thank you for providing the link. For unknown reasons i can not include  this      #include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>. It is because inside Qt3dRender there is no QCamera class.

Comment: I have not tried the above post but i guess this should work. Hence marking your ans as right.

Comment: :- I tried your suggestion however the program crashes at line cBox->addWidget(graphicsView);